# LUIS with Microsoft Bots Sandwich Formbuilder

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I followed the instructions on how to create a sandwich order with using the formbuilder.
I would like the form talk. i  thought the best approach is to use LUIS. I created the Luis app.
Are you able to combine a LUIS app with the formbuilder? Any tutorials?

Comment: What do you mean by form talk?

Comment: Produce audible output.Any help appreciated!thanks!

Comment: Luis is not used for audio, it's for understanding language. Which channel have you deployed your bot?

Comment: i am planning to deploy my bot to MS teams, can you suggest a way to produce audio output that would work with the bot, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speech is not support on MS Teams. Webchat, DirectLine channel, and Cortana are the only channels that support speech.

> The Bot Framework now supports speech as a method of interacting with the bot across Webchat, the DirectLine channel, and Cortana.

[[1](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/26/speech-to-text/)]